# 1119: Access of possibly undefined property x through a reference with static type flash.utils:Timer

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

i keep getting this error code i am new to actionscript and i am trying to have multiple objects moving from right to left. Any advice would be great if i'm taking the wrong approach.

```
public class MainGame extends MovieClip
{
    private var enemy_startx = 600;
    private var enemy_starty = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 + 400 - 1)) + 1;
    private var enemy:Timer = new Timer(200);

    public function startGame()
    {
        enemy.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,enemyHandler);
        enemy.start();
    }

    private function enemyHandler(event:TimerEvent):void
    {           
        var speed = 15;
        this.x = enemy_startx;
        this.y = enemy_starty;
        enemy_startx = enemy_startx + speed;    
    }
}
```

Comment: This part of your code is probably not the part that is throwing some error. Please post all the relevant parts.

Comment: somewhere you are trying to set a timer instance `x` property.  are you doing `enemy.x` somewhere in your code?   Also, I don't think you want to move your entire game x/y position every timer tick (assuming `MainGame` is your document class).

Comment: Consider giving your variables more meaningful names. Specifically your `Timer` in the code shown.  Though some philosophers may say "time is your enemy" - for the context of game development, your timer would probably be more relevantly named `scrollTimer` or something like that (as it looks like all you want it to do is scroll some things across the screen)

Comment: Strong type your variable and don't initialize them at class level, do that in constructor instead. That piece of code cannot throw that error.

Comment: This link will show you all the code that i have.
http://hastebin.com/zeziyoxaye.scala